# List of nodes pointing to parent C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, nodes

I am storing custom data structures in a list, each one points to it's parent.

Here is the data structure

```
struct block{
    int someVal;
    block * parent = 0;
}
```

I need to fill a list with 'block's and each one needs to point to its parent, I initialise as follows:

```
block Q;
std::vector<block> something;   // assume this is filled with 4 blocks
```

I init the first object in the list to have the parent point to itself (easy way to identify the last element)

```
something[0].parent = &something[0];
```

As for setting the others, this is my logic:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    something[i].parent = &Q;
    Q = something[i];
}
```

Now, this looks like it should produce something like:

```
something[0].parent = #address of itself
something[1].parent = #address of 0
something[2].parent = #address of 1
something[3].parent = #address of 2
```

But really it's assiging everything to the memory location of something[0]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I cannot copy the original code because of the complexity and scope, I just hope I've recreated the problem in this question.

Comment: you should be aware that the moment that vector has to expand or contract every pointer and reference to *every* element within becomes invalid, *including the `parent` pointers you're trying to maintain.* You would probably be better off storing container indexes rather than parent pointers.

Comment: Of course! I thought I was going mad, that makes a lot of sense.